# Relation between the roots of $x^2+x+1$ and its derivative

Tags: calculus, polynomials, roots

If $f(x)$ is a polynomial in n degree and has  $n$ real roots then is it necessary that $f'(x)$ has to have $n-1$ real roots? If this is so then $x^2+x+1$ has no real roots but the derivative of the polynomial has a root. Is it correct to conclude this?

Comment: You've found a counterexample to the claim "if $f(x)$ has $n$ real roots then $f'(x)$ has $n-1$ real roots".

Comment: This statement should be true if you add the assumption that $f(x)$ is a degree $n$ polynomial, yes? Between any two adjacent zeros, you should be able to find a zero of $f^\prime (x)$ by the Mean Value Theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a polynomial $f(x)$ has $n$ real roots, then we can look at the (real) graph of $f(x)$. Now when a polynomial is zero you can have two situations:

1. The polynomial intersects the $x$-axis
2. The polynomial merely touches the $x$-axis

In the first case we can say that if our polynomial should have another root, than is has to "travel back to the $x$-axis". In other words: it has to undergo a change in its (vertical) direction, wich is only possible if the derivative is zero somewere.

So the important thing is that you now realise that between two consecutive roots, there is necessarily  some sort of turning point/horizontal tangent/root of the derivative.

If you think this through a little you will be able to derive your statement.

---

If you look at case two  your statement need not be true. However the fact that we have $n=\deg(f)$ ensures us this won't happen.

Comment: The derivative is 0 at x=-1/2 so it means that the it the curve changes its vertical direction.So then it must have two real roots.How would you explain this?

Comment: @user You should really read my answer more carefully. Moreover you really need to learn what the words necessary and sufficient mean, as was suggested by Yves Daoust. It seems to be of great confusion to you.

Comment: My direct question is that why doesn't the concept that the derivative of a n degree polynomial has n-1 real roots applicable to x^2+x+1?

Comment: The key thing you're missing here is really the difference between nessecity and sufficiency, plus you have to read the conditions of your statement more carefully, since $x^2+x+1$ does not satisfy them. There really is no other way of properly explaining this.

Answer (score 1):

The derivative has a root because deg=1. No problemo because the implication goes in the other direction.

Comment: What implication are you referring to?

Comment: Suppose a polynomial f(x)=ax^4+bx^3+cx^2+dx+e has double derivative which has 2 real roots the can we say that f(x) has 4 real roots?

Comment: @user2866839, I'm saying the same that Yves Daoust. Is true that $(x^2+x+1)'$ has a root but not *because* ($f$ has $n$ roots $\implies$ $f'$ has $n-1$ roots). The reverse arrow ($f'$ has $n-1$ roots $\implies$ $f$ has $n$ roots) is *false*.

Answer (score 1):

It is a necessary but not sufficient condition. You are challenging the "sufficient" property, not the "necessary" one.

Comment: I could not get you.Can you please be specific.

Comment: Learn the proper terms. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necessity_and_sufficiency